# How to add text to video frame/s using ffmpeg?

Tags: image, video, ffmpeg

What I need is that I am looking for command that helps me add a text on video for few frames. For example, there is door with a empty name plate in a scene. I should be able to write name to it and it should move as the door moves. after door disappears, so should the text. Can I do it using ffmpeg or any other tool in linux. TIA

Answer (score 0):

What you want to do is something called "Motion Tracking" and I don't think ffmpeg can do it with command line options.

Henry Kroll has some work using ffmpeg, gstreamer, python and some other methods. Start from [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GDr95vtZcg8) and [here](http://thenerdshow.com/motion%20tracking.html).

You may also want to check [ARToolkit](https://artoolkit.org/about-artoolkit)

Comment: thanx a ton. will took into it